# Dynamic email generation based on User Data and Content Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Within Marketing Cloud, we have a Data Extension periodically imported from a CMS system that contains roughly 3,000 entries of Users. A User has 1 to 20 topics in comma-delimited format. The same CMS system publishes a limited amount of content daily, give or take 5-10 content pages, where the content page is tied to multiple topics. We would like to have the ability to email a daily content alert to each user with a list of the content titles and urls that pertain to the user's topics.

The first option I found was to use AMPscript Function Reference [HTTP Get](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httpget.htm) to make a call to an RSS Feed and append the user's topics to the query string in order to return the appropriate content to something like a dynamic content block. But with over 3,000 users with different topic values and the inability to cache responses, this would either take forever or completely timeout at some point.

The second option I found was to use [content syndication](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_content_syndication.htm&type=5), where parts of the request url can be replaced with the subscriber's topic attribute value. Within the [performance preservation guidelines](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_system_performance_preservation.htm&type=5), it states that the list size should be kept below 1,000 subscribers. The content syndication [HTTPGet Command](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_content_syndication_in_api.htm&type=5) states `If the content is cached, the system includes the cached copy; otherwise, the system accesses the URL.`, so I'm wondering if this is an internal cache that salesforce controls in order to reduce requests, as that would be more than ideal for performance and might be our ticket to resolution if it can handle more users. A downside to this approach would be having to hit the delivery environment for every different permutation of the user's topics (100+ times).

Otherwise, is it possible to have the content pages as another data set within marketing cloud to be queried per user (grab record from the content pages data set where any user topics match content page topics) and then rendered within the email? Or is it considered bad practice to include non-contact data in this system? I am basically looking to automate this per user in a performant fashion, even if it means having some other work around such as creating another temporary data set that is a list of users with a generated content field that gets created every day.

Comment: Hi, your last paragraph outlines a common approach. data extensions are meant to be freely defined, it's totally fine to have non-contact data in them. So I would go for a content DE in which your content is structured for email personalization at the time of send. If you don't go completely crazy with the amount of lookups per person, performance with 3k users is of absolute no concern with this approach.

Comment: @JonasLamberty - what sort of numbers do you think begin to pose a performance problem? In a similar use case, I'm looking to have a DE of a user's events for a given day, to use AMPscript to pull them into one message ('you have the following notifications on your account') and could be dealing with 100k users and a content DE with many millions of rows. Will create a separate question if needed!

Comment: Is there a particular AMPscript function that can return the rows from the content data extension where any topics match the user's topics? It looks like a Lookup function may be possible? I keep forgetting that these field types are just plain text and not arrays or dictionaries.

Comment: @Antonio short answer is, your numbers wouldn't make me worry too much. Long answer is dependent on too many factors, like "what do you consider a problem", "what is your precise usecase", "what do you actually do in terms of lookups", "what are your DEs and primary keys",... etc. If you write a separate question, then include those. But yeah, your numbers sounds reasonable. check this for a gut feeling of what numbers SFMC considers "high" https://factory42.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/f42allgemein/pages/1355415589/Marketing+Cloud+Performance

Comment: @BenSewards you might want to check out lookup(), lookuprows(), lookupOrderedRows() that you can find documented. start here https://ampscript.guide/lookup/